# Runtime Error: Incomplete output while executing buy function for cs50 finance

Tags: python, sql

While all the checks work, (empty symbol, invalid number of shares...), the function fails to actually purchase the stocks. It returns an internal server error. Following is the log output:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 71, in _execute
raise RuntimeError(exc.orig) from None
RuntimeError: incomplete input

Following is my buy function:

```
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        # access symbol and stock
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        stock = lookup(symbol)

        # ensure valid symbol
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Please enter a valid symbol")
        elif not stock: #if symbol is invalid then none will get allocated to stock, which we dont want
            return apology("Invalid symbol")

        # access the number of shares and check for an integer
        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except:
            return apology("Shares must be an integer")

        # if shares are negative
        if shares <= 0:
            return apology("Shares must be a positive integer")


        user_id = session["user_id"]
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)[0]["cash"]

        stock_name = stock["name"]
        stock_price = stock["price"]
        total_price = stock_price * shares

        # check for sufficient funds
        if total_price > cash:
            return apology("Insufficient funds.")
        else:
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", cash - total_price, user_id)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, name, shares, price, type, symbol) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?",
                        user_id, stock_name, shares, stock_price, 'buy', symbol)

        flash("Bought!")
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

Following is my HTML code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    buy
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="symbol" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="shares" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Following is my SQL table:

| field | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, |
| user_id | INTEGER NOT NULL, |
| name | TEXT NOT NULL, |
| shares | INTEGER NOT NULL, |
| price | NUMERIC NOT NULL, |
| type | TEXT NOT NULL, |
| symbol | TEXT NOT NULL, |
| time | TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id) |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, name, shares, price, type, symbol) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", 
user_id, stock_name, shares, stock_price, 'buy', symbol)
```

Could it be that this statement needs to have a closing round bracket in VALUES?

```
 db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, name, shares, price, type, symbol) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", 
user_id, stock_name, shares, stock_price, 'buy', symbol)
```

Comment: I don't think so. I have used the format correctly.

Comment: Checked, the error seems to be hinting to a missing close brace. I believe you should try to close the round bracket in values to solve your problem. 

Even if it's not the root of your issue, it's gonna be a problem anyways later.

To be more explicit `VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?" ` should become `VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);" `

Comment: Hey, I just checked, yeah you were right. I missed a closing parenthesis, though the semi colon is not required. Thank you so much! Appreciate the effort you have taken. :D